# Google Map Places autocomplete api throws an error when called through ajax

Tags: google-maps, location, jquery-autocomplete

Am trying to auto suggest the names of location (using jquery autocomplete) as the user types into the location box by connecting it to the google maps places autocomplete api. But the ajax response throws me an error.

But when I copy and paste the same api url in the browser directly it returns me back the results.

what am I doing wrong?

**API url:**
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=cola&sensor=false&key=[my key]

**Screenshot from my firebug**

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7ZMqGCQDtvkcEhsUTVQWTJhWXc/edit?usp=sharing

**jQuery Code**

```
jQuery("#my_location").autocomplete(
{
    source: function( request, response ) 
    {
        jQuery.ajax(
        {
            url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json",

            type: "GET",


            data: {
                        input: request.term, //jQuery("#my_location").val(),
                        sensor: "false",
                        key: [my key]
            },

            success: function( data ) 
            {
                response( $.map( data.predictions, function( item ) 
                {
                    return {
                        label: item.description, //item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
                        value: item.description
                    }
                }));

                //console.log(data);

            },

            error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) 
            {
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown)
            }

        });
    },

    minLength: 2

}); // autocomplete
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is because of CORS. Forgive for a non solution answer but maybe it's useful as a guideline.